# fetching managed object vs fetching specific values

Tags: ipad, nsfetchrequest

Let´s assume I have created a core data entity with:

```
NSDate *firstDate
NSDate *secondDate
NSData *image
```

When executing a fetch with executeFetchRequest, is the request then fetching the whole image with it or just the pointer to the image?

In other terms: Does it make a big difference performance and memory wise if I fetch all the entities or just an NSDictionary with firstDate/secondDate when I do not need the image directly?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your NSFetchRequest behavior. Read [Fetching Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) document from Apple.

Comment: thanks, I read that I can also setPropertiesToFetch etc. but my questions were if the fetch request is fetching the whole image or just the pointer and if it makes a difference in performance or memory.

Comment: I would say pointer as Core Data uses lazy loading by default. Anyway, i would use the `setPropertiesToFetch` method even if they are just pointers.